# Reversing a Doubly Linked List Issues

Tags: c, reverse, doubly-linked-list

I am trying to reverse a Doubly Linked List with no success.  After reversing, the list appears to be empty.

Here is my implementation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct Item Item;
typedef struct DLL DLL;

struct Item {
    int value;
    Item* next;
    Item* prev;
};

struct DLL {
    Item* head;
    Item* tail;
    int size;
    void(*add)(DLL*, int);
    void(*addToTail)(DLL*, int);
};

void add(DLL* list, int val) {
    Item* new_item = (Item*) malloc(sizeof(Item));
    if (new_item == NULL) {
        exit(-1);
    }
    new_item->value = val;
    new_item->next = list->head->next;
    list->head->next = new_item;
    new_item->prev = list->head;
    list->size++;
}

void addToTail(DLL* list, int val) {
    Item* new_item = (Item*) malloc(sizeof(Item));
    if (new_item == NULL) {
        exit(-1);
    }
    new_item->value = val;
    new_item->prev = list->tail->prev;
    list->tail->prev = new_item;
    new_item->next = list->tail;
    list->size++;
}

Item* find(DLL* list, int val) {
    Item* iter = list->head->next;
    while (iter != list->tail) {
        if (iter->value == val) {
            return iter;
        }
        iter = iter->next;
    }
    return NULL;
}

void reverse(DLL* list) {
    Item* current = list->head;
    Item* temp = NULL;
    while (current != NULL) {
        temp = current->next;
        current->next = current->prev;
        current->prev = temp;
        current = current->prev;
    }

    temp = list->head;
    list->head = list->tail;
    list->tail = temp;
}

void printList(DLL* list) {
    Item* iter = list->head->next;
    while (iter != list->tail) {
        printf("%d\n", iter->value);
        iter = iter->next;
    }
}

DLL* initDLL() {
    DLL* list = (DLL*) malloc(sizeof(DLL));
    if (list == NULL) {
        exit(-1);
    }

    // Creating head & tail
    list->head = (Item*) malloc(sizeof(Item));
    list->tail = (Item*) malloc(sizeof(Item));
    if (list->head == NULL || list->tail == NULL) {
        free(list);
        exit(-1);
    }

    // Initializing head & tail values just for testing
    list->head->value = 100;
    list->tail->value = 200;

    list->head->prev = NULL;
    list->head->next = list->tail;
    list->tail->prev = list->head;
    list->tail->next = NULL;

    list->size = 0;
    list->add = add;
    list->addToTail = addToTail;

    return list;
}

int main() {
    DLL* my_list = initDLL();
    my_list->add(my_list, 1);
    my_list->add(my_list, 2);
    my_list->add(my_list, 3);

    printList(my_list);
    // Outputs:
    // 3
    // 2
    // 1

    reverse(my_list);

    printList(my_list);
    // Prints nothing since list->head->next == list->tail
}
```

I expected

> ```
> 3
> 2
> 1
> 1
> 2
> 3
> ```

but get only

> ```
> 3
> 2
> 1
> ```

The first `printList()` works as expected, but the second produces no output.

Looking into the problem I've found that after reversing the list, for some reason `list->head->next` is pointing to `list->tail`, even though there are 3 elements in the list.

I've searched online for examples but stumbled upon implementations which don't use a `DLL` structure such as mine, but only `Node` structure.

Comment: I don't see why you need to actually reverse a DLL. You could have a function to print from the tail to the head.

Comment: It's for studying purposes.

Comment: That's a lot of code for a [mcve].

Comment: make a function which traverses and shows list from tail to head, this is the reverse of doubly linked-list

Comment: @melpomene "Make sure all information necessary to reproduce the problem is included"

Comment: @melpomene, it is a lot of code, but there doesn't seem to be anything that can be omitted.  I think it's a well-asked question.

Comment: Please read and understand [the question on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in C](/q/605845).  For example, in this code, prefer `Item* new_item = malloc(sizeof *new_item);`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your add function, you need to set `new_item->next->prev` to `new_item` after setting `new_item->next = list->head->next;`

```
void add(DLL* list, int val) {
    Item* new_item = malloc(sizeof *new_item);
    if (new_item == NULL) {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    new_item->value = val;
    new_item->next = list->head->next;
    new_item->next->prev = new_item;   // <--- This is missing in your code 
    list->head->next = new_item;
    new_item->prev = list->head;
    list->size++;
}
```

Similar issue is in your `addToTail()`. There you need to set `new_item->prev->next` to `new_item`.